# Can a trait guarantee that it is inherited by a companion object at compile- or run-time

Tags: scala, traits, companion-object

I have a trait for which the initialization is *not* inherently thread-safe, but is intended strictly for use as a base for companion objects, for which initialization *is* thread-safe by definition.

Is there some way to guarantee (either at compile- or run-time) that the trait is always extended by a companion object?  The trait has a method that is always and only called during companion-object initialization, which could be the site of the verification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the trait must be extended by exactly 1 object, you can check it at compiletime like this:

```
trait Foo { this: Bar.type =>
  ...
}

object Bar extends Foo
```

If you need several objects to extend it, you could try something based on the `Singleton` magical type:

```
trait Foo { this: Singleton =>
  ...
}
```

but I don't know if that works.

Comment: Yes, if it wasn't clear, I need multiple objects to inherit the trait, so only the Singleton suggestion is germane.  With it, Intellij complains about "Illegal Inheritance, self-type Bar.type does not conform to Singleton".  The compiler (2.10.4) is fine, though.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution checks the number of constructors of the child class, it is based on the observation that objects have 0 constructors while classes have at least 1.

The check happens at runtime.

```
trait Y {
  // objects have 0 constructors, everything else has >= 1 constructors
  require(getClass.getConstructors.length == 0, "Trait Y should be extended by objects only")

  def hello(): Unit
}

class Foo$ extends Y {
  def hello() = println("Hello Foo$")
}

class Foo extends Y {
  def hello() = println("Hello Foo")
}

object Bar extends Y {
  def hello() = println("Hello Bar")
}

object Test extends App {
  new Foo().hello()  // exception is thrown
  new Foo$().hello()  // exception is thrown
  Bar.hello()  // prints Hello Bar
}
```